# How to solve Sitecore Lucene rebuilding index issue on Content Delivery Server after raising publish end event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

For a blog created on Sitecore 8.2 we are using Sitecore Lucene indexing. The blog is working fine with an exception for the duplicated content which appears after a publish.

To solve the issue of duplicated contents is quite easy, click in the admin on Control Panel, go to Indexing Manager and rebuild the custom indexes, but that is not the way how it should work.

I expect that the indexes are rebuild automaticly after a publish, and, I configured the strategies for that.

```
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/rebuildAfterFullPublish" />
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
            </strategies>
```

I want to rebuild the indexes from confuration file and not directly from programcode.

On CD-environment I see in the log 0 units processed.

```
ManagedPoolThread #0 12:54:21 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=features_blog_web_index (units processed: )
```

It looks like the job was triggered after the publish end event, but I do not get what's going exactly wrong.

For me, it's a little bit unclear, where I should look for the solution. I can rebuild the indexes on Content Management Server (CMS), and, after a rebuild, the contents are even on Content Delivery Server (CDS) not duplicated anymore. Is it the CMS or CDS server where the problem is?

Hope someone experienced with Sitecore Lucene can give me some guidance to solve the issue. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Jordy

Comment: A slight tangent, but are you using SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex?

Comment: Not sure how similar this is to your issue, but might assist: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2463273

Comment: Which update of 8.2 are you on? There were some index rebuilding issues in early updates if I recall.

Also, for scaled environments, you really should not be using Lucene and should be using Solr or another centralized indexing engine.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene

Comment: I use Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161221 (Update-2)

Comment: No, SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex is not configured.